# Sets equipped with sublattice of their power sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lattice-orders

Topology and measure theory are two examples of fields which include, in their objects of study, sets which are given structure by equipping them with a lattice of a certain type sitting in their power set. Are there other examples of this pattern?

Comment: See [field of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets)

Answer (score 1):

A bornology is an example too.

A convexity structure is not a lattice (not closed under unions, just under
intersections and *directed* unions), but does have the "feel" of a topological structure, to me at least.

A convergence space is a set $X$ and a relation on the set of ultrafilters on it times $X$, etc. So such "second order" (or higher order) structures are not uncommon. Not always lattice based, though.